# Checking the availability of a word within a phrase, in a given position

Tags: c++, string, c++14

Please let me know how can I check whether the first word of a given  string is "echo" ,ignoring if any spaces before the word.

Example:

```
string hello = "    echo hello hihi";
if(startwith(hello, "echo")
{
    //some code here
}
```

Please help me if possible

Comment: Split the words into a `std::vector<std::string>` and check the 1st element in that one.

Comment: The first letter of a string cannot be `"echo"`, because `"echo"` is a string with four characters (not including the nul terminator).    The most you can do is check that the first four letters, in order (and consecutively if that is your requirement), match the characters in `"echo"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string_view` has a similar functionality. Just skip the white space and use that.

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

using std::string, std::string_view;

constexpr bool StartsWithSkipWs(string_view const str,
                                string_view const prefix) noexcept {
  auto begin = str.find_first_not_of(" \t\n\f\r\v");
  if (begin == string_view::npos) return false;
  return str.substr(begin).starts_with(prefix);
}

int main() {
  string hello = "echo hello hihi";
  if (StartsWithSkipWs(hello, "echo")) 
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using namespace std; 

int main(){
 string hello = "    echo hello hihi";
 boost::trim_left(hello);
 string subst=hello.substr(0,4);
 if(subst=="echo"){
  ////some code here
 }
}
```